# gnome-control-center crashed

Tags: gnome, upgrade

I tried to upgrade Gnome 3.10 to Gnome 3.12 in Ubuntu 14.04, but the upgrade was not successful and `gnome-shell --version` shows `3.10.4`.
`gnome-control-center` crashes showing:

```
(gnome-control-center.real:22243): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot derive 'GnomeControlCenter' from non-fundamental parent type 'CcShell'

(gnome-control-center.real:22243): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gnome-control-center.real:22243): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
[1]    22243 segmentation fault (core dumped)  gnome-control-center
```